# Firebase snapshot.ref.parent is possibly 'null'

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make this [firebase sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase/functions/index.js) to work:

```js
// Listens for new log added to /log/:pushId/original and creates an
// uppercase version of the log to /log/:pushId/uppercase
exports.db_uppercaseLog=functions.database
.ref('/log/{pushId}/original')
.onCreate((snapshot)=>{
  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  const original = snapshot.val();
  const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
  // Return a Promise
  return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
});
```

The above code can run if I deploy it directly from `index.js`. But it won't compile in TypeScript. TS lint raise the following error:

```
> functions@ build D:\Firebase\stax8\functions
> tsc

src/index.ts:94:10 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.

94   return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Found 1 error.
```

Trying to fix the problem by isolating it this will raise another problem:

```js
  if (snapshot.ref.parent){
    return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
  }

// > TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.
```

**How to fix this problem?** Is the case of a null parent possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the API documentation, [snapshot.ref.parent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference.html#parent) can be null by definition.  The code you show is correctly checking that:

```
if (snapshot.ref.parent) {
  return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
}
```

But the second error message is telling you that your function isn't returning anything in the case where parent might be null.  If you don't ever expect it to be null (because you're certain that the provided DataSnapshot will always have a parent), simply return null:

```
if (snapshot.ref.parent) {
  return snapshot.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
}
else {
  return null;
}
```

That will satisfy the TypeScript compiler that you've considered all possible cases.

Comment: the onCreate event expect a return Promise. is it ok to return null instead of promise? @Doug Stevenson

Comment: You can return null if you don't have any async work to complete.

Answer (score 2):

This is because in your `tsconfig.json` file you have the following :

```
strictNullChecks : true
```

You can either change it to false or you can use optional chaining:

```
return snapshot?.ref?.parent?.child('uppercase').set(uppercase)
```

You can check here for more info:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#--strictnullchecks